# How to convert from raw pointer to unique pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, unique

So, I thought that by converting from raw pointer to unique pointer was not hard at all. However, as I am trying to attempt to do one for myself, I run into a lot of problems that I don't even know of. This example below will explain more what I mean. I got a lot of errors from Visual Studio that I don't know how to fix it. Can I anyone tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you

```
Contact.h

#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>

class Contact
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Contact& c);
    friend class ContactList;

public:
    Contact(std::string name = "none");

private:
    std::string name;
    //Contact* next;    
    std::unique_ptr<Contact> next;
};
```

Contact.cpp

```
#include"Contact.h"

using namespace std;

Contact::Contact(string n):name(n), next(new Contact())
{
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Contact& c)
{
    return os << "Name: " << c.name;
}
```

ContactList.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Contact.h"
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

class ContactList
{
public:
    ContactList();
    ~ContactList();
    void addToHead(const std::string&);
    void PrintList();

private:
    //Contact* head;
    unique_ptr<Contact> head;
    int size;
};
```

ContactList.cpp

```
#include"ContactList.h"
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

ContactList::ContactList(): head(new Contact()), size(0)
{
}

void ContactList::addToHead(const string& name)
{
    //Contact* newOne = new Contact(name);
    unique_ptr<Contact> newOne(new Contact(name));

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head.swap(newOne);
        //head = move(newOne);
    }
    else
    {
        newOne->next.swap(head);
        head.swap(newOne);
        //newOne->next = move(head);
        //head = move(newOne);
    }
    size++;
}

void ContactList::PrintList()
{
    //Contact* tp = head;
    unique_ptr<Contact> tp(new Contact());
    tp.swap(head);
    //tp = move(head);

    while(tp != 0)
    {
        cout << *tp << endl;
        tp.swap(tp->next);
        //tp = move(tp->next);
    }
}
```

I updated by using swap function to swap the content between pointers.

Here is all the errors that I get

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   E:\Fall 2013\CPSC 131\Practice\Practice\Debug\Practice.exe  1
```

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ContactList::~ContactList(void)" (??1ContactList@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall ContactList::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GContactList@@QAEPAXI@Z) E:\Fall 2013\CPSC 131\Practice\Practice\Practice\ContactListApp.obj

Comment: It's better if you paste the errors you got. Or the first ones if they're a lot.

Comment: One issue I see, I believe you have to use std::move to assign between unique ptrs. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr. Initialising to nullptr in your constructor should work though. It would help to paste the errors you are getting.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: I did copy and paste the errors up there. Would you take a look and tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) has empty constructor and nullptr constructor, it says nothing about 0.

```
constexpr unique_ptr();
constexpr unique_ptr( nullptr_t );
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p );
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 );
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 );
unique_ptr( unique_ptr&& u );
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u );
template< class U >
unique_ptr( auto_ptr<U>&& u );
```

also, you're going to want to use [`void swap(unique_ptr& other)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/swap) to swap pointers between unique_ptrs without deconstructing them as would happen with the [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D). Try again with all that in mind, you should take a good look at the [cppreference.com unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) page to understand how it works.

On a second note with linked lists if I were you I'd use raw pointers.

Comment: _On a second note with linked lists if I were you I'd use raw pointers._ - Could you give an explanation for this advice?

Comment: @ComicSansMS I simply don't see the point of using unique_ptr in linked lists when you can manually delete the pointers. I see it as a unnecessary performance overhead as they bring no utility other than making it much more complicated such as in the case above. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My reasoning is opposite to yours: Preventing leaks in code that can throw exceptions is considerably harder when using raw pointers. So I see it as an unnecessary complexity overhead not to use unique_ptr here. Performance overhead of unique_ptr should be 0 on any modern compiler, so that's no argument for me.

Comment: @EdwardA: I did edit my code and use swap function like you suggested, however it is still wrong. Would you please take a look and tell me what I did wrong int there ? Thank you very much.
PS: and what is the difference between swap function and move function. They seem to do exactly the same thing to me...

Comment: @user2383193 using `move` + `=operator` will move the pointer out of the old `unique_ptr` into the new one but will call delete on any pointer that was stored in the `unique_ptr` that you're moving into. The `unresolved externals` error you're getting now is because you didn't define a deconstructor for `ContactList`: (`unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ContactList::~ContactList(void)"`).

Comment: @user2383193 and `void ContactList::PrintList()` is all wrong, `unique_ptr<Contact> tp(new Contact()); tp.swap(head);` the `new Contact()` is pointless as you're going to break everything by swapping he head with the new one you just creating (`tp(new Contact()`) and its going to ruin the whole linked list. What you're going to want to do in the `PrintList` is have a `Contact* curr` `curr = head.get()` `while (curr) { ..print.. curr = curr.next.get() }`. There probably are more errors than that in your  code, my suggestion is to start it over after having read the cppref   link in my answer.